# Python still throwing exception I've explicitly excepted

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, index-error

I've got some code that I know will fail in the edge case where the list is empty so I added exception handling for `IndexError`.

But, despite handling the exception, it's still getting raised.

```
~/Code/foo.py in decode_tokens(tokens)
    196                 new_toks.append(new_tok)
    197             else:
--> 198                 try: new_toks[-1] += new_tok
    199                 except IndexError: pass
    200             new_elem = True

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand how if I'm explicitly excepting `IndexError` why it's still getting raised and aborting script execution.

Edit: adding that this is Python 3.6 running in a Jupyter notebook. As it looked like a python error I didn't think that was relevant (but it sounds like it might be.)

Comment: How about showing us what the statement looks like in your code? Could you please update your question with a [mcve]?

Comment: I cannot reproduce

Comment: I don't recognize that run environment. Are you running in a debugger? Some may still show exceptions, though the script shouldn't fail. What do you see if you run your script from the command line?

Comment: Let's go for a slightly more far-flung issue. Are you using Spyder/Enthought Canopy or something else supporting IPython?

Comment: @brunns - this is in a jupyter notebook. Unfortunately I'm not sure if I can easily reproduce the actual state in the command line as it's the result of a long-running ML model (took ~4 hours before it generated output that failed). I will try with synthetic input.

Comment: In that case, if you have modified the modules while the code was running, it's quite possible that the exception is a horrible coincidence. Jupyter has an underlying IPython kernel and it's very possible to get line mismatches when an exception is thrown in a module that has since been edited. Restart the kernel

Comment: @roganjosh - that sounds like it's possible. I added this exception handling into the library after I hit the error last night and it was dynamically reloaded. Could you please leave that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editors that support IPython, which include Jupyter, do not always reload modules even after they have been edited. I think this might be an unfortunate coincidence; the line that the error is thrown happens to coincide with the line of your exception handler *after* an edit. Likely the code that threw the error isn't what's at that line now. You may wish to force a reload of imported modules each time you run a script, or at least restart the underlying IPython kernel for now.

Comment: I added the exception handling because this line threw an `IndexError` last night. The module should have been reloaded with `%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2` but I think you're right that something funky went on and it didn't actually reload the exception-handling code properly.

Comment: Ahhhhh, reloaded the kernel and now see what the _actual_ issue was with reloading the module. It failed to do so silently (but still showed the updated code in the error message)! I added the hotfix exception handling with a different editor on the server that added tabs instead of spaces: "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation". Thanks for the pointer in the right direction!

Comment: @BradDwyer I would have preferred to answer with more detail on how it works in IPython but I don't have a detailed-enough grasp on how all these mismatches come about. Certainly I have seen bizarre tracebacks where line content doesn't match my actual script, but many other issues can arise.

Comment: No worries, I just needed the point in the right direction. I was going down the wrong rabbit hole thinking maybe `IndexError` was somehow special or I was doing error handling incorrectly.